# Div on top of leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

How can I make the text appear on the map  ? , I tried making the div relative and doing z-index=9999 but its still above it and not on top of it

[image]

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context .